# Asyncfileupload not working in Firefox

Tags: asp.net, ajax, firefox, asyncfileupload

I'm making an asp.net website, in it I have an Asyncfileupload control which is inside an updatepanel.
It works fine in Chrome & other browsers but it doesn't work in FireFox..
Please help..

Comment: Please explain how it is 'not working' - a client-side JavaScript error? Not triggering UploadedComplete? Not including the file contents when the callback occurs?

Comment: Can you please include which browser versions you are working with, and which version of the ASP.NET AJAX toolkit you are using?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the width of the AsyncFileUpload control using css:

Follow below Steps:

- Apply CssClass on ajaxToolkit:AsyncFileUpload like "imageUploaderField"
- Write Css(".imageUploaderField input{width:100%!important;}")

If the result is the same, update your ajax toolkit with the latest edition.

**References:** [AsyncFileUpload with Firefox 22.0b1](http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/workitem/27429)

If it still doesn't work then it could be a Firefox bug.

Comment: Any ideas how to fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

yah but for that you should check it in codeplex,
there is some some javascript changes..

Comment: I checked codeplex out.. couldn't find anything.. Can u send me a link?

Comment: The file hasn't changed since the most recent release, unless he is talking about other forks, pull requests, or something attached to a work item.

http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/31deee62fbe2#Server%2fAjaxControlToolkit%2fAsyncFileUpload%2fAsyncFileUpload.pre.js